# How to modify node.js script to use Form-Data to post a image file using axios

Tags: node.js, axios, form-data

I am new to node.js and would like some pointers on how to change the below function in node.js server to use Form-Data to post a image using axios.
The below code works successfully but only for text files.

I need to upload pdf and image files as well via a Rest API but the below method doesnt work if I use fs.readFileSync to populate fileContent - it is uploaded but cant be viewed.

The form-data library using append appears to be what I need but not sure how to convert the information in fileData to form.append method.

```
async function UploadAttachment(req, res) {
    let fileName = req.fileName;
    let Key = req.TokenKey;
    let fileContent = req.fileContent;
    let fileData = `--*****MessageBoundary*****\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="payload"\nContent-Type: application/xml; CHARACTERSET=UTF-8\n\r\n<attmnt>\n  <repository id="1002"></repository>\n  <orig_file_name>${fileName}</orig_file_name>\n  <attmnt_name>${fileName}</attmnt_name>\n  <description>Upload File</description>\n</attmnt>\r\n\n--*****MessageBoundary*****\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="${fileName}"; filename="${fileName}"\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n\n${fileContent}\n\n--*****MessageBoundary*****--\r`;

    try {

        let res = await axios({

            method: 'POST',

            url: `http://server_name:8050/caisd-rest/attmnt?repositoryId=1002&serverName=server_name&mimeType=Text&description=test.txt`,

            data: fileData,

            headers: {

                'Accept': 'application/xml',

                'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=UTF-8',

                'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',

                'User-Agent': 'Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)',

                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',

                'X-AccessKey': `${Key}`

            }

        });

        res.data;

        });

        return res.data

 

    } catch (err) {

        logger.info("error in Upload " + err);

        throw Error(err)

    }

}
```

Comment: One of your `content-type` headers is incorrect for the request body

Comment: Thanks Phil - that has led me to a solution which is to encode file first with certutil and change Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution which is to encode file first with certutil and change `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`